# PHP return value... what am I missing?

Tags: php, return-value, return-type

Shouldn't the function return value ($checkZero) be false (boolean)?
The result of the following is 'zero is zero'. What am I missing?

```
class CheckZero {
    function __construct() {
        $zero = 3;
        if ($zero === 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

$checkZero = new CheckZero();
if (!$checkZero) {
    echo 'zero is not zero';
}
else {
    echo 'zero is zero';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `return` from a class constructor.  What is returned is the newly created object.

If you `var_dump` the return value, you'll see that an object was returned:

```
object(CheckZero)#1 (0) {
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I knew I was overlooking something obvious. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor prototype:

```
void __construct ([ mixed $args [, $... ]] )
```

This means that the return value of `__construct` is discarded and useless, because it is the object itself that is returned.

If you run `var_dump($checkZero);` then you would see that it is an object of clas `CheckZero`.